# Passing data between components while calling navigateByUrl method

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I have two components called UserRegistration and ListAllUsers.

My use case is when user complete the registration on UserRegistration component then the success message should be shown on the ListAllUsers component page.

I have redirect the page using `this._router.navigateByUrl('/user/all');` this line of code, where _router is the object of Router module of angular 2.

Now How do i pop up the success message from the ListAllUser component when user complete the registration on UserRegistration method.

```
onCreateUser() {
this.getCheckedValues();
this.model.roles = this.checkedValues;
this._httpService.createNewUser(this.model)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.status = JSON.stringify(data["status"]),
        this.description = data["description"],
        this.error_user_name = data["description"]['user_name'],
        this.error_password = data["description"]['password']
    },
    error => alert(error),
    () => {
      if(this.status.includes("S1000")){
        this._toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
        this._router.navigateByUrl('/user/all');
      }else if(this.status.includes("E1000")){
        this._toasterService.pop('error', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
      }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better and easier to set a timeout with a toaster showing success and then redirect after like 1 second ?

Comment: Do I need to set it on my UserRegistration Component

Comment: Yes, I would do it just before `this._router.navigateByUrl('/user/all');`.

So that you can display a toaster or anything like that to tell the user that the registration was successful, and then redirect them to the next component.

Comment: I try the way you told. But it failed. It just redirect to another page does not show any toast

Comment: Does it work that way ? I don't really know if the toastr keeps being displayed since you navigate to your other component directly after displaying the toaster.
Maybe you need to set a timeout function before navigating so that would let the time to the user to see the toastr.
Check this out : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: If you want to keep your first idea, you can also just set a state in your service (like an isRegistered boolean that is set on success register) and in your other component display a message on the ngAfterViewInit() event if the isRegistered is at true.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I have change my code like this but I could not get the value on isRegistered as true

Comment: `this._httpService.isRegistered = true;
            this._router.navigateByUrl('/user/all');`

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this._httpService.isRegistered)
    if(this._httpService.isRegistered) {
      this._toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
    }
  }`

Comment: This should be working, can you do a plunkr ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131693/discussion-between-nifcody-and-alex-beugnet).